# return a variable from a Dyanmic SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql, remote-server

I have the below code which is checking physical file counts to confirm that a previous process has generated the correct number of files (in different folders)

```
set NOCOUNT ON

declare @DateOffset int

set @DateOffset=0

-- Create a table variable to store user data
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
(
    docID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    docRef VARCHAR(10),
    YPTMPID varchar(3),
    saveDir VARCHAR(500),
    totalLettersExpected int,
    actualLetters int 
);

insert @myTable SELECT docRef, YPTMPID,
    saveDir=max(Save_Directory) + cast(YEAR(GETDATE()-@DateOffset) as varchar(4)) + '\'  + datename(month, GETDATE()-@DateOffset) + '\'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(20), GETDATE()-@DateOffset, 101),4, 2) + '.' + LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), GETDATE()-@DateOffset, 101), 2)
    + '.' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(20), GETDATE()-@DateOffset, 101),7, 4),
    COUNT(*) as 'Total Letters', null
  FROM [alpsMaster].[dbo].[uExtractMonitor]
  group by docRef, YPTMPID
  order by 1,2



-- Get the number of rows in the looping table
DECLARE @RowCount INT, @SQL nvarchar(4000), @LoopSQL nvarchar(4000), @Date varchar(20)

set @Date=rtrim(CONVERT( CHAR(12), getDate()-@DateOffset, 106)) --'29 Oct 2013'
SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(docID) FROM @myTable) 

-- Declare an iterator
DECLARE @I INT

-- Initialize the iterator
SET @I = 1

-- Loop through the rows of table @myTable, and for each docRef, check the file directory for the correct number of files
WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @docRef VARCHAR(10), @saveDir VARCHAR(500), @TemplateID varchar(3), @letterCount int
        DECLARE @statement nvarchar(200), @EQRecordCout int

        -- Get the data from table and set to variables
        SELECT @docRef = docref FROM @myTable WHERE docID = @I
        SELECT @saveDir = saveDir FROM @myTable WHERE docID = @I        
        SELECT @TemplateID = YPTMPID FROM @myTable WHERE docID = @I 

        update @myTable set actualLetters = 0 where docRef=@docRef

        create table #files (subdirectory varchar(100), depth int, [file] int)
        insert into #files  EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @saveDir,0,1;    

        -- *** PROBLEM HERE ***
        set @statement= 'SELECT count(*) FROM BOCTEST.S653C36C.LIVEBOC_A.' + @docRef
        print @statement

        exec @EQRecordCout=sp_executesql @statement
        print @EQRecordCout

        select @letterCount = COUNT(*) from #files 
        print cast(@letterCount as char(3)) + '  files for ' + @docRef 
        drop table #files
        update @myTable set actualLetters = @letterCount where docRef=@docRef-- and YPTMPID=@TemplateID

        -- Increment the iterator
        SET @I = @I  + 1        

END

select * from @myTable

set NOCOUNT OFF
```

Inside my final `WHILE LOOP` I want to get a count of the records in each file on the iSeries remote server using Dynamic SQL (with the table name `docRef` at the end of the SQL string being dynamic)

But even though it execute fine, all I get into the variable **@EQRecordCout** is a zero. This is incorrect, although some of the tables are empty, most have records in them

What is the correct way to write this to return a value?

```
set @statement= 'SELECT count(*) FROM BOCTEST.S653C36C.LIVEBOC_A.' + @docRef
print @statement

exec @EQRecordCout=sp_executesql @statement
print @EQRecordCout
```

thanks
Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `output` parameter with `sp_Executesql` like this

```
DECLARE @intCount int
SET @statement = 'SELECT @numRecords = count(*) FROM BOCTEST.S653C36C.LIVEBOC_A.' + @docRef
EXEC    sp_Executesql  @statement, N'@numRecords int output', @intCount OUTPUT 
PRINT   @intCount
```

**Check here :** [Extract value returned from dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201023/extract-value-returned-from-dynamic-sql)

Comment: thanks, you submitted your answer just before I did!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sp_executesql` with an `output` parameter.  Remember to specify `output` twice:

```
set @statement= 'SELECT @rc = count(*) FROM BOCTEST.S653C36C.LIVEBOC_A.' + @docRef

declare @rc int
exec sp_executesql @statement, N'@rc int output', @rc output;
```

Comment: thanks I got there by doing some research but the code in the answers provided is easier to read!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the **MS Technet Library** at [Microsoft Technet: sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

here is the `WHILE LOOP` code that works:

```
WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @docRef VARCHAR(10), @saveDir VARCHAR(500), @TemplateID varchar(3), @letterCount int
        DECLARE @statement nvarchar(200), @EQRecordCount int
        DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

        -- Get the data from table and set to variables
        SELECT @docRef = docref FROM @myTable WHERE docID = @I
        SELECT @saveDir = saveDir FROM @myTable WHERE docID = @I        
        SELECT @TemplateID = YPTMPID FROM @myTable WHERE docID = @I 

        update @myTable set actualLetters = 0 where docRef=@docRef

        create table #files (subdirectory varchar(100), depth int, [file] int)
        insert into #files  EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @saveDir,0,1;    

        SET @ParmDefinition = N'@EQRecordCountOUT int OUTPUT';
        set @statement= 'SELECT @EQRecordCountOUT=count(*) FROM BOCTEST.S653C36C.LIVEBOC_A.' + @docRef
        --print @statement

        execute sp_executesql @statement,@ParmDefinition, @EQRecordCountOUT=@EQRecordCount OUTPUT;
        print @EQRecordCount

        select @letterCount = COUNT(*) from #files 

        drop table #files
        update @myTable set actualLetters = @letterCount, EQRecordCount=@EQRecordCount where docRef=@docRef-- and YPTMPID=@TemplateID

        -- Increment the iterator
        SET @I = @I  + 1        
    END

select * from @myTable
```

so it's necessary to pass in the OUTPUT Parameter that you want populated into a variable.